# Get cyrillic result from latin characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in sql server and I am trying to search for some results using the `LIKE` function.

Example:

```
Column1
"abc"
"абц"
```

As you can see, there are both, latin and cyrillic, strings.

My question:

Is it possible, a query like this: `select * from table1 where column1 like '%ab%'`(or `'%аб%'`), to give me the both results ?

more info: I am making a web site in asp.net and I need this for searching. I'm using vs2012 and sql server 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIKE` behaviour depends on collation, which in your case must be `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`.

CI stands for case-insensitive. So this means that for example 'Ц' and 'ц' will be treated the same in searhes.
AS stands for accent-sensitive. This has no meaning in cyrillic anyway.

To my knowledge, there is nothing in collation which would describe how latin characters are mapped to cyrillic.
Here is the problem:
Should latin 'c' be mapped to cyrillic 'ц' or 'c', , or 'к', or 'ч'? Or maybe 'в' because it is the 3rd in alphabet?
Should cyrillic 'ц' be mapped to latin 'c' or 'z'?

However, this is possible to do in the business layer of your ASP.NET website.
There you have freedom to setup your mapping according to the business needs.
Whenever the user passes 'ab' as a parameter - you can create a pair of 'ab' and 'аб' out of them, and pass both to your stored procedure or ad hoc query:

```
select *
from table1
where column1 like '%ab%' or column1 like '%аб%'
```

P.S. Beware that having % before your search term will be slow if you have millions of records: 
`LIKE 'ab%'` can use index seek, `LIKE '%ab%'` cannot.

Comment: Thank you for the info and the alternative query, I never thought of OR in the query.